# Out of date file being requested from a PHP script that no longer references it?

Tags: php, apache2

I'm running a LAMP stack on Amazon EC2 for an AJAX focussed application written in PHP with APC caching.  I'm sorry if this is the wrong forum but I don't really know if the problem is my server or my code.

One particular ajax call (which always has unique parameters) in my app returns some html with an iframe in it with myphpfile.php as the src (to force evaluation of myphpfile.php - there are better ways to do it sure, but I couldn't find them years ago when I wrote the code!).  Yesterday I changed the src variable to myhtmlfile.html and yet there are still clients out there requesting the old myphpfile.php despite there being no reference to it anywhere on my server.

I have cleared the APC cache (by doing an apache2 restart).  The vast majority of users are going to the new file, but still 1 or 2 per minute or so are going to the old file (that's not much % of my traffic, but I like to take care of my traffic!).  The ones still using the old file tend to be iphone users.

I just have no idea where it could be getting any reference to the old myphpfile.php - it isn't in the php file, not in the apc cache.  What else do I have to clear?

Comment: Is it in a JavaScript file that's getting cached?

Comment: Is it possilbe that they simply have the old link bookmarked? If this is the case, you could simply but a "header('location: myhtmlfile.html');" in myphpfile.php.

Comment: No, it was never exposed to the user.

Comment: Everything is exposed to the user. There's nothing stopping a user from getting the source of a particular iFrame.  Admitedly not the average user but I wouldn't bet against it.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're absolutely correct that there could be malicious intent.  However, looking at the AJAX request they make (which then returns the iframe) it does not look to be malicious - it looks like something somewhere is out of date - I just can't figure out what the heck it could be since the AJAX request is made to a php script which then returns both the data and the iframe.  Perhaps I should just leave it for a few days - if it is an out of date problem then giving it time is the easiest way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yesterday I changed the src variable to myhtmlfile.html and yet there
>   are still clients out there requesting the old myphpfile.php

I have requests for files that have been gone for years. Sometimes there's just no stopping them.

> but I like to take care of my traffic!). The ones still using the old
>   file tend to be iphone users.

If you haven't done so already, you can have Apache send the html file to users so you don't have to worry about them receiving 404's. Simply use `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myphpfile\.php myhtmlfile.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks.  The only additional variable here is that the new file myhtmlfile.html is stored on Amazon's CDN rather than the EC2 server.  ie, rather than mywebsite.com/myphpfile.php it needs to go to static.mywebsite.com/myhtmlfile.html.  Will the rewrite engine redirect that "far" (ie, off the server?)